# Linux does not see a file until I ls on that directory

Tags: files, php, nfs

I have a really weird problem.  I have a php script that runs, submits a child process to run, and waits until its done by checking for a OUTFILE.end file to appear.  The problem is the file appears, but the php script doesn't see the file.  I tracked it down to a Linux problem, since if I check using the command line, Linux doesn't see it.

```
[katelyn@katelyn data]$ ls ./files/OUTFILE.end
ls: cannot access ./files/OUTFILE.end: No such file or directory
```

I know the OUTFILE.end file is there since the child job stopped running.  The second I `ls` on the directory, the file then appears.

```
[katelyn@katelyn data]$ ls -l ./files/
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 katelyn katelyn  0 Sep 10 16:30 OUTFILE.end
-rw-rw-r--. 1 katelyn katelyn 19 Sep 10 16:30 OUTFILE.txt
[katelyn@katelyn data]$ ls ./files/OUTFILE.end
./files/OUTFILE.end
```

I am running CentOS release 6.5, and the ./files/ directory is actually a symlink to another folder that happens to be on a Luster distributed filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to attribute caching.  The NFS client doesn't want to send packets for every check.  It assumes that for a short period of time it can answer questions about individual files from its cache.  However in your case, the cache is no longer valid.

Directory lookups are not answered from cache.  Instead it really sends a READDIR or READDIR+ over the network and updates the cache.

Try turning down the `actimeo` option on your mount to reduce the time the cache is kept valid.

Comment: I have found that this will last pretty much indefinitely (at least an hour), basically until I do the `ls`.  On my server `actimeo` is not specified in my fstab, so I assume it defaults to 60 seconds, however I see lags of more than an hour.  
I suppose I can just do a quick directory listing in my php code `$temp = \`ls ./files/\`;`

Comment: Have you tried setting it lower?  Another option you can try is to set `lookupcache=none` (or possibly to pos).  That will make it always do lookups (but can affect performance).